# Inconsistent query results depending on the order of the query in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, match, with-statement

[image 1[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8s67.png)

Depending on the order I query 2 relationships, I get 2 different answers despite the query being the same (as far as I understand). The query obviously is not the same but I don't know why.

```
MATCH p1=(:Barrier {code: 'B2'})-[:REL1]->()
WITH count(DISTINCT p1) AS failed_B2
MATCH p2=(:Barrier {code: 'B2'})-[:REL2]->()
RETURN count(DISTINCT p2) AS worked_B2, failed_B2
```

Returns 1 and 0 - which is correct

But the other way round:

```
MATCH p1=(:Barrier {code: 'B2'})-[:REL2]->()
WITH count(DISTINCT p1) AS failed_B2
MATCH p2=(:Barrier {code: 'B2'})-[:REL1]->()
RETURN count(DISTINCT p2) AS worked_B2, failed_B2
```

Returns 0 and 0 - which is incorrect

I would like to combine the results of multiple queries but UNION does not work because it needs to group the results under the same column which in my case would be incorrect. I need the results in different columns.

Comment: Can you try these queries with `PROFILE` and Share the results here?

Comment: there is error in second query `WITH count(DISTINCT p2) AS failed_B2`
it should be `(DISTINCT  p1)`

Comment: Govind, thanks, that was just a typo in the question. Raj, how do I use PROFILE?

Comment: Raj, I attached an image  but cannot attach the second one

Comment: Which version of Neo4j are you using? While using a similar graph (one pattern that has a count of 1, and another that doesn't exist), when the one that doesn't exist is first, I get a match to your results, but not the other way around. I don't get 0, 0, I get no rows returned, which is VERY different, and that difference is important.

Comment: The fix in your case, when you don't know if a pattern will exist or not, is to use OPTIONAL MATCH instead of MATCH, but I'll save that for my answer later, and after you confirm your Neo4j version, and whether you're really getting 0,0 back, or if instead you are getting no rows but misinterpreting that as zeros being returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is an interesting thing that centers around what happens when rows get filtered out (such as when a MATCH fails or a WHERE condition filters the row).

But first we need to address that you observed in the second case: `Returns 0 and 0`. I don't think that's really true, and I'd like to know what version of Neo4j you're using here. In this particular case, I would have instead expected no rows being returned, and this is ENTIRELY different than a row being returned with 0 values for both.

When Cypher queries execute, they build up records (or rows) of data. And Cypher operations execute per row. So when you do a MATCH in some point in your query, that's being performed per row, and when the MATCH fails, when no such pattern exists (that adheres to your WHERE clause, if present), then the row is filtered out. This is important, because this means that any other data in that record is gone and no longer addressable.

The second thing to keep in mind is that we allow certain aggregations such as `count()` and `collect()` to execute *even when no rows are present*, as it is conceivable that you may have a query where nothing matches, and getting that count of 0 (or that empty collection when you collect) is an entirely valid case and should be allowed. In these cases, where there may not have been any rows left at all after a MATCH or filter (and because of no rows, nothing else would be able to execute, as Cypher operations execute per row, so it's no-op if there are no rows), the `count()` or `collect()` would cause a new row to emerge with that count of 0, or that empty collection. And since a row is now present, the remaining operators in the query have something to execute on, and the query can continue execution.

This is what happens in your first case, where pattern `p1` doesn't exist, but pattern `p2` does (once). Here's the breakdown of what happens:

1. The first match fails to find anything. Rows go to 0. There is nothing left to execute subsequent operations upon.
2. You perform a standalone `count()` aggregation (with no other variables in scope, this is important). This emits a single row with a count of 0, which is correct: there are no occurrences of that pattern in the graph.
3. You perform the second MATCH, and there is a record/row for it to execute upon (with the value `{failed_B2:0}`), and it finds the single occurrence, and gets its count (1), and is able to output the expected answer (1, 0), with the 1 being the count of the pattern matches at the end of the query, p2, and the 0 being the count of the pattern matches from the first two lines of the query, p1.

Now let's see what happens when we reverse this.

In your second query, it is now pattern `p1` that exists once in the graph, and pattern `p2` that doesn't exist. Here's the breakdown that happens:

1. The first MATCH succeeds and finds the pattern.
2. You get the count of the patterns found: 1. You now have a single record/row with the value `{failed_B2:1}`
3. You execute the second MATCH, and the pattern isn't found. The record/row is filtered out. You now have no records/rows, so not only is there nothing to operate on, anything that was previously in the record/rows is gone. There IS no `failed_B2` value anywhere to reference.
4. You attempt to get the count of the `p2` along with `failed_B2`. But this isn't allowed by Cypher, we only allow aggregation across 0 rows when it's a standalone count() or collect(), there IS no `failed_B2` to reference, it was wiped out when the record/row that contained it got filtered out. There is no way to process that sanely, as that previously existing data is just not there (and this is correct behavior). The query **should** be returning no rows...which is NOT the same as `0, 0`, as that implies you got a row returned (which is why I'm interested in clarifying that point with you).

As for how you should be correctly executing this, when you have to aggregate like this and you know that some patterns may not exist, use an OPTIONAL MATCH instead.

When you OPTIONAL MATCH, it doesn't filter out the row if no match is found. Instead newly introduced variables in the pattern go to null, and when you count() or collect() over nulls, it ignores them, giving you a correct count of 0, but not wiping out the record/row that contains the `failed_B2` value you also want to return at the end.

Comment: InverseFalcon this all makes sense and you are correct! What an excellent explanation!